# Website freezes in checkout on a multistore Magento 2 installation

Tags: magento2, checkout, javascript, multistore

My default store works perfectly fine. I recently created a second store (each store is accesible through its own domain name) on the same magento installation and I noticed one error/bug in the checkout process.

After entering customer data in the first step of checkout, I click on "Continue" and the loading icon keeps spinning forever and there is nothing I can do to stop it or cancel. If I want to browse the store again I have to reload the website.

I attach 2 images of the Console logs. On the 2nd website I got some errors but dont know what they mean. The errors on the console appear when I click on the "Continue" button after filling the shipping information. Then the website freezes and the loading icon spins forever.

I've tried multiple times cleaning magento cache, browser cache, deploy static content, etc., but nothing works.

[image: Console main website]
[image: Console second website]

[image: XHR response]

[image: Developer mode test]

EDIT - New screenshot from Response tab:

[image: Response tab]

It is worth mentioning again that the main store works perfectly fine. This issue occurs only in the 2nd store.

Complete code from response tab:

{"payment_methods":[{"code":"cashondelivery","title":"Pago en Oxxo / 7-Eleven"},{"code":"banktransfer","title":"Dep\u00f3sito o transferencia bancaria"}],"totals":{"grand_total":489,"base_grand_total":489,"subtotal":359,"base_subtotal":359,"discount_amount":0,"base_discount_amount":0,"subtotal_with_discount":359,"base_subtotal_with_discount":359,"shipping_amount":130,"base_shipping_amount":130,"shipping_discount_amount":0,"base_shipping_discount_amount":0,"tax_amount":0,"base_tax_amount":0,"weee_tax_applied_amount":null,"shipping_tax_amount":0,"base_shipping_tax_amount":0,"subtotal_incl_tax":359,"shipping_incl_tax":130,"base_shipping_incl_tax":130,"base_currency_code":"MXN","quote_currency_code":"MXN","items_qty":1,"items":[{"item_id":786,"price":359,"base_price":359,"qty":1,"row_total":359,"base_row_total":359,"row_total_with_discount":0,"tax_amount":0,"base_tax_amount":0,"tax_percent":0,"discount_amount":0,"base_discount_amount":0,"discount_percent":0,"price_incl_tax":359,"base_price_incl_tax":359,"row_total_incl_tax":359,"base_row_total_incl_tax":359,"options":"[]","weee_tax_applied_amount":null,"weee_tax_applied":null,"name":"Alcanc\u00eda de cer\u00e1mica"}],"total_segments":[{"code":"subtotal","title":"Subtotal","value":359},{"code":"shipping","title":"Shipping & Handling (Est\u00e1ndar - 1 a 4 d\u00edas h\u00e1biles)","value":130},{"code":"tax","title":"Impuestos","value":0,"extension_attributes":{"tax_grandtotal_details":[]}},{"code":"grand_total","title":"Total","value":489,"area":"footer"}]}}

NEW EDIT: Added response from estimateshipping xhr

[image: Estimate shipping XHR]

Code:
[{"carrier_code":"tablerate","method_code":"bestway","carrier_title":"Est\u00e1ndar","method_title":"1 a 4 d\u00edas h\u00e1biles","amount":130,"base_amount":130,"available":true,"error_message":"","price_excl_tax":130,"price_incl_tax":130}]

Comment: Have you tried this commands: php bina/magento cache:flush, php bin/magento setup:di:compile, php bin/magento setup:static:deploy?

Comment: Yes, I've tried that already but doesn't work

Comment: Please share website URL if you can it will help to identify the issue.

Comment: Please disable minifying, bundling and merging JS files if they are enabled and share changes in browser console with us.

Comment: I've already added changes in console

Answer (score 0):

The error that there's an error in your JSON config most likely means that a PHP error occurs. A custom extension could be the fault.

To debug this, open the `Network`-tab in your developer console and check the actual response of the XHR request.

It's also better to debug this on a local or development machine where you can set the deploy mode to "developer". This will disable minifying the Javascript files and you will see where the error exactly occurs.

Also check your system.log and exception.log files, as well as the webserver's error log files for PHP errors.

==EDIT==

I assume you are using Firefox, so this is where you have to look to get the error message (while in developer mode):

[image]

In my case it is a CSS file but that really does not make a difference - the response tab will show you the error message.

Comment: Added screenshot from Network tab

Comment: Added screenshot from test in developer mode

Comment: edited my answer

Comment: Added screenshot from Response tab

Comment: Do you have the response from the estimateshipping xhr?

Comment: I added response from estimate shipping XHR

Comment: was your Magento running in developer mode when the screenshots were taken?

Comment: Yes, Magento was running in developer mode